# How to set the total time taken in hh:mm:ss format in Extent report 3.0.6

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, testng, extentreports

[How to set the time taken in hh:mm:ss format?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtwF4.png)

Till 2.41.2 time taken is shown in hh:mm:ss format only but in latest its showing in ms format.

Is there any configurations available in Extent  3.0.6 ?

Can anyone done this setup before please share your idea?

Comment: htmlReporter.config().setTimeStampFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); -- http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#htmlreporter-configuration

Comment: @Grasshopper Tried this one already but its not changing the total time taken field value. It changing the date values alone in the report

Comment: Look at this example: http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#testng-ireporter

Comment: @Ankur Same setup only i have done as mentioned on that example, here the thing is in latest extent report total time taken is displaying in milliseconds only. I want to know is there any option to change it.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its fixed in latest extent version